# Sitecore Commerce extend sellable items

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine, commerce-catalog, commerce-server

I want to show a long description on my product detail page which will contains some html within it i.e. it should be entered via rich text editor and its up to author to add bullet points, long text , text  highlighter, numbers to decorate the long description.
I can see there is an option to use composer templates to extend the sellable item schema. However, I didn’t see any datatype for rich text. Its only allow String, Data time, Decimal, Integer, Boolean.
Is it possible to add new data type in commerce entity? Any hep is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use a field type like RichText.

```
var viewProperty = new ViewProperty()
{
    Name = "RichText Title",
    UiType = "RichText"
};
 
entityView.Add(viewProperty);
```

BizFx uses WYSISWYG Rich text editor.

More details here: http://andrewsutherland.azurewebsites.net/2018/10/02/business-tools-ui-hints-and-ui-types/#html